# Angular 9 onclick function not defined

Tags: javascript, angular

dashboard.component.ts

```
myFunction(){
      console.log("test");
  }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<img [src]="team.logo" onclick="myFunction()" alt="img">
```

Whenever the image is clicked, error appears in console saying "Reference error: myFunction is not defined". I have tried using ng-click aswell but no luck.

Comment: Angular should be `(click)="myFunction()"`, have you tried that?

Comment: `ng-click` is the old angularJS (aka angular 1) syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do the following,

In your dashboard.component.html file,

```
<img [src]="team.logo" (click)="myFunction()">
```

Comment: yes that gets the job done!

Comment: same answer posted below

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Both the answers got posted in or around the same time frame.

Comment: A minute difference, for exactly the same answer. (Hence upvotes vs downvotes)

Comment: @AustinTFrench I don't know as the timestamp shows no difference. Should I delete my answer? As I am a new contributor to this forum, please advise.

Comment: The accepted answer is not a great answer... I'd read the comments on the OP, and current accepted answer and here and expand your answer (edit, add info)

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh No need to post duplicate answers! Yes there is a time difference of 1m and 23 seconds! i am not sure why OP chose your answer though

Comment: @Sajeetharan - The difference appears to be 28 seconds. Note to @thisdotukarsh: you can see the exact post time in the tooltip of the line that says `answered XX mins ago`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use event named **`(click)`** with angular

```
<img [src]="team.logo" (click)="myFunction()" alt="img">
```

Comment: yes that works, and why would ng-click not work in this situation?

Comment: ng-click is with angularjs (1.x)

Comment: ng-click is not an Angular binding. It was in AngularJs which is very different.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular , we use (click) function instead of onClick.